# Sorting elements in a dictionary based on the values of elements

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python with various numerical elements, each with a string as a key.

Example:
`ex_dict = {"text1" : 63 , "text2" : 71 , "text3" : 3}`

I was wondering if there was a way for me to sort the elements of the dictionary based on the numerical values for each key; using a function that would output:

`sorted_dict = {"text2" : 71 , "text1" : 63 , "text3" : 3}`

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? In Python 3, the default dictionary is ordered by insert order, for example.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Does this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value ?

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
ex_dict = {"text1" : 63 , "text2" : 71 , "text3" : 3}
{k: v for k, v in sorted(ex_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)}
```

output

```
{'text2': 71, 'text1': 63, 'text3': 3}
```